# Why are the $Q_i$ unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension

I am studying the theorem:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1. Then every non-zero ideal $I$ of $R$ has a unique expression as a product of primary ideals with distinct radicals.

Proof. Let $I=⋂_{i=1}^nQ_i$  such that $Q_i$ are primary and each $P_i=rad (Q_i )$ is maximal since $R$ is of dimension 1. Since no $P_i⊆P_j$ for $i≠j$ then $P_i$ are embedded primes and hence the $Q_i$ are unique. The $P_i$ are pairwise comaximal ($P_i+P_j=R$ for all $i≠j$) whence so are the $Q_i$. It follows  that $Q_1∩…∩Q_n=Q_1…Q_n$.

Conversely if $I=Q_1'…Q_m'$ where $Q_i'$ are primary with distinct radicals $P_i'$. As before the $Q_i'$ are comaximal, so $I=∏_{i=1}^mQ_i' =⋂_{i=1}^mQ_i'$ . By uniqueness of decomposition, $m=n$ and $Q_i=Q_i'$ after permuting.

I am not understanding why $P_i$ are maximal? Moreover where it is used the fact that $R$ is of dimension 1?
Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $R$ being dimension 1 domain means that  the length of the longest chain of prime ideals can be 1

Answer (score 1):

... and each $P_i=nilrad(Q_i)$ is maximal since $R$ [is $1$-dimensional]

Is that what you mean? It kind of looks like you didn't finish typing it. You would need $1$-dimensionality to conclude that these nonzero primes were maximal...

Comment: @Yes, that is what I mean. I think that if $P_i$ is not maximal we have that $P_i$ is properly contained in a maximal ideal of $R$, say $M$. Then we have that for $i\neq{j}$ $P_i,P_j$ are contained in a maxima ideal. Is this the required contradiction?

Comment: @User1999 Yes, I suppose you are basically proving the simple lemma that in a $1$ dimensional domain, nonzero primes are maximal.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. One more question please... Why the $Q_i$ are unique?

Comment: $P_i\neq P_j\implies Q_i\neq Q_j$.

Comment: @User1999 You should probably look at what you're asking. How could you  get more than one thing for the nilradical of a single ideal?

Comment: Iam really sorry to disturb you again but I am not understanding why $Q_i=Q'_i$ for $I=⋂_{i=1}^mQ_i'=⋂_{i=1}^nQ_i$?